# How to prevent a trigger firing during a batch job?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a batch job that updates accounts. There is also an after trigger (just to make life more complicated).

I want that the trigger will not fire during the batch job.

I wrote a global validator class, and trying to control run's with it.

```
global class Validator_CLS{
    private static boolean blnAlreadyDone = false;

    public static boolean hasAlreadyDone(){ return blnAlreadyDone; }
    public static void setAlreadyDone() { blnAlreadyDone = true; }   
}
```

Batch works: calls the global class - sets parameter to true

Batch:

```
public class SF2NSUpdateOpportunityNSId{

    public static void collectData(){

        if(Validator_cls.hasAlreadyDone())
        {
            system.debug('no need to run again');
            return ; 
        }
...... Alot more code here
```

When trigger fires, it needs to NOT run if parameter is true.

Trigger:

```
trigger trgSF2NSAccount on Account (after update,after insert) {

    system.debug('trgSF2NSAccount + Validator_cls.hasAlreadyDone ' + Validator_cls.hasAlreadyDone());
    if(Validator_cls.hasAlreadyDone())
    {
        system.debug('no need to run again');
        return ; 
    }
.... A LOT more code here as well
```

Something is wrong.

The trigger keeps firing

Comment: are you sure you are not missing setting the value to true during batch like Validator_CLS.setAlreadyDone();

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `!system.isBatch()` in your trigger to check if it is fired from within a batch or not

Comment: This perfectly resolved my similar situation. Thanks Sven

Comment: You are welcome. If this answers the question then please mark it as a correct answer. thx

Comment: Thanks I was also looking for this similar information, so now it means that when you create a trigger on object to trigger from UI while entering data the same will apply while a insert of data happening using a Batch job on that object, if we want to avoid that trigger to be fired during batch we can put suggested condition to avoid that. Thanks So much.

Answer (score 3):

`System.isSchedulable()` might be a more precise method.  `System.isBatch()` is true on both Batchable and Queueable jobs.

Comment: Almost 5 yrs after this answer, it's now `System.isScheduled()`, and this would only help if the batch was scheduled, not if it was executed directly.  Also, the docs now say that `isBatch()` only returns true for a Queueable in API v35.0 and earlier.  There is now `System.isQueueable()` (and `System.isFuture()`).  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_isBatch